# ng-route not displaying templateurl instead displaying json data from node server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean-stack

I'm working on freecodecamp voting app (https://www.freecodecamp.com/challenges/build-a-voting-app) using MEAN stack. I've completed back end part(does not include user authentication as of now).

Currently i'm focusing on front end part. I've created a html page which displays the list of all the polls. Now ideally speaking, when i click on a particular poll, i should be redirected to a template html which displays the options as well as the vote count for each option. For this purpose i've used ng-route library. But instead of getting the html page, i'm getting json array from node server.

Here are my code snippets:

***index.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html lang="en"  class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/routes.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/poll-read-controller.js"></script>
  <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/dist/js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/app.css">
</head>
<body class="background" ng-app="votingApp">

  <!-- div for button group><!-->
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" aria-label="...">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="home">Home</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="login">Log In</button>
  </div>

  <!-- div for header><!-->
  <div class='header'>FreeCodeCamp Voting App</div>

  <!-- div for voting list><!-->
  <div ng-controller="VotingListController as v">
    <ul class='list'>
    <li class='question row' ng-repeat='poll in v.polls'><a ng-href='/{{poll.question}}'>{{poll.question}}</a></li>
    </ul>  
  </div>
  <poll_view></poll_view>   



</body>
</html>
```

***app.js***

```
(function(){
// Declare app level module which depends on views, and components
var ang = angular.module('votingApp', ['ngRoute']);
ang.controller("VotingListController",['$scope','$http','$location',function($scope,$http,$location){
  var list = this;
  $http.get('https://fcc-voting-app-ajinkya009.c9users.io/list').success(function(data){
    list.polls=data;
  });
}]);
})();
```

***routes.js***

```
(function(){
// Declare app level module which depends on views, and components
var ang = angular.module('votingApp')
          .config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider){
              $routeProvider
              .when('/:question',{
                 templateUrl:'/../template/poll_view.html',
                 controller:'pollReadController',
                 controllerAs:'pollRead'
              });
          }]);
})();
```

***poll-read-controller.js***

```
(function(){
    angular.module('votingApp')
    .controller('pollReadController',function($http,$routeParams){
       var controller = this;
       $http.get('https://fcc-voting-app-ajinkya009.c9users.io/'+$routeParams.question).success(function(data){
          controller.vote = data; 
       });
    });
})();
```

***poll_view.html***

```
<div ng-repeat="vote in pollRead.vote">
    <ol>
       <li>
           <p>Option:{{vote.option}}</p>
           <p>Count:{{vote.count}}</p>
       </li> 
    </ol>
</div>
```

and here's a sample json data I'm getting instead of html page:

```
[
    {
        _id: "57d90d6bbb1828e112ff70dc",
         question: "google or yahoo",
        __v: 0,
        vote: [
                {
                  option: "google",
                  count: 2,
                  _id: "57d90d6bbb1828e112ff70de"
                },
                {
                  option: "yahoo",
                  count: 0,
                  _id: "57d90d6bbb1828e112ff70dd"
                }
             ]
    }
]
```

***server/index.js***

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var app = express();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var polls = require('./models/poll');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var port = 8080;
var ip = process.env.IP;
var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/meanapp');
var poll = db.model('poll',polls);
mongoose.connection.once('open', function() {

  console.log('Listening on port: '+ port);
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + "/../client")));
  app.use(bodyParser.json());
  app.set('view engine','html');
  //app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  //app.use(express.methodOverride());
  //app.use(app.router);

  // Add Middleware necessary for REST API's
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(methodOverride('X-HTTP-Method-Override'));

// CORS Support
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
  next();
});


  app.get('/list',function(req,res){
    console.log('received')
    poll.find({},function(err,list){
        if(err)throw err;
        res.json(list);
    });
  });

   app.get('/:question',function(req,res){
    poll.find({question: req.params.question},function(err,data){
        if(err)throw err;
        res.json(data);
    });
  });

  app.post('/question',function(req,res){
      var p = new poll({question:req.body.question,vote:req.body.vote});
      p.save(function(error){
          if(error){
              throw error;
          }
          res.json(p);
      });
  });

  app.put('/:question',function(req,res){

     poll.update(
         {
           "question": req.params.question,
           "vote.option":req.body.option
         },
         {$inc:{"vote.$.count":1}},
         function(error){
             if(error)throw error;
         }
     );
     res.json(poll);
  });

  app.put('/question/update/:id',function(req,res){


     poll.update(
         {"_id":req.params.id},
         {"$set":{"question":req.body.question,"vote":req.body.vote}},
         function(error){
           if(error)throw error;
         }
     );

  });



  app.listen(port);
});
```

Here's link to my project: https://ide.c9.io/ajinkya009/fcc_voting_app

P.S. I'm learning MEAN stack since two months(quite beginner), so if you find any mistake in the code,no matter how trivial, please let me know.

Comment: You don't seem to have an ng-view here, so ngRoute has nowhere to display it's data.  Also, you aren't showing what the links from the API look like, but it sounds like they are direct links to the API, not links to your route.

Comment: I've tried ng-view option as suggested but still it is not working. I've added the server/index.js file for reference. Please have a look.

Comment: you don't seem to have any route on the server for GET `/:question`.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Put up the wrong file. Now I've updated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it!! I had not added 'fragment identifier' (#) in the anchor href link in index.html. Along with this, I had to tweak some of the other code as well.

Here is the updated and working code:

***index.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html lang="en"  class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/routes.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/poll-read-controller.js"></script>
  <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/dist/js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/app.css">
</head>
<body class="background" ng-app="votingApp">

  <!-- div for button group><!-->
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" aria-label="...">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="home">Home</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="login">Log In</button>
  </div>

  <!-- div for header><!-->
  <div class='header'>FreeCodeCamp Voting App</div>

  <!-- div for voting list><!-->
  <div ng-controller="VotingListController as v">
    <ul class='list'>
    <li class='question row' ng-repeat='poll in v.polls'><a ng-href='#/list/{{poll.question}}'>{{poll.question}}</a></li>
    </ul>  
  </div>
  <div class='container' ng-view></div>



</body>
</html>
```

***client/app.js***

```
(function(){




// Declare app level module which depends on views, and components
var ang = angular.module('votingApp', ['ngRoute']);

ang.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',function($routeProvider,$locationProvider){
              $routeProvider
              .when('/list/:question',{
                 templateUrl:'/../template/poll_view.html',
                 controller:'pollReadController',
                 controllerAs:'pollRead'
              });
              //$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
          }]);


ang.controller("VotingListController",['$scope','$http','$location',function($scope,$http,$location){
  var list = this;
  $http.get('https://fcc-voting-app-ajinkya009.c9users.io/list').success(function(data){
    list.polls=data;
  });
}]);

ang.controller('pollReadController',function($scope,$http,$routeParams){
       var list = this;
       alert($routeParams.question);
       $http.get('/list/'+$routeParams.question).success(function(data){
          list.polls = data;
       })
       .error(function(){
           alert("An unexpected error occured!");
       });
    });



})();
```

***client/poll_view.html***

```
<div class='container' ng-repeat="poll in pollRead.polls">
    <h2>{{poll.question}}</h2>
    <div ng-repeat = "v in poll.vote">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <p>Option:{{v.option}}</p>
                <p>Count:{{v.count}}</p>
            </li> 
        </ul>    
    </div>

</div>
```

***server/index.js***

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var app = express();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var polls = require('./models/poll');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var port = 8080;
var ip = process.env.IP;
var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/meanapp');
var poll = db.model('poll',polls);
mongoose.connection.once('open', function() {

  console.log('Listening on port: '+ port);
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + "/../client")));

  app.use(bodyParser.json());
  app.set('view engine','html');
  //app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  //app.use(express.methodOverride());
  //app.use(app.router);

  // Add Middleware necessary for REST API's
//app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
//app.use(methodOverride('X-HTTP-Method-Override'));

// CORS Support
/*app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
  next();
});*/


  app.get('/list',function(req,res){
    console.log('received');
    poll.find({},function(err,list){
        if(err)throw err;
        res.json(list);
    });
  });

   app.get('/list/:question',function(req,res){
    poll.find({question: req.params.question},function(err,data){
        if(err)throw err;
        res.json(data);
    });
  });

  app.post('/question',function(req,res){

      console.log(req.body);
      console.log(req.body.vote);

      //res.json({success:"200"});
      var o = req.body.option;
      var c = req.body.count;
      /*var p = new poll(
          {question:req.body.question,vote:{option,count}}
          );*/
      var p = new poll({question:req.body.question,vote:req.body.vote});
      p.save(function(error){
          if(error){
              throw error;
          }
          res.json(p);
      });
  });

  app.put('/:question',function(req,res){

     poll.update(
         {
           "question": req.params.question,
           "vote.option":req.body.option
         },
         {$inc:{"vote.$.count":1}},
         function(error){
             if(error)throw error;
         }
     );
     res.json(poll);
  });

  app.put('/question/update/:id',function(req,res){

     console.log(req.params.id);
     console.log(req.body);
     poll.update(
         {"_id":req.params.id},
         {"$set":{"question":req.body.question,"vote":req.body.vote}},
         function(error){
           if(error)throw error;
         }
     );

  });



  app.listen(port);
});
```